# PWA with Push notifications running on Windows IIS

Tags: javascript, iis, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

So i'm trying to create a PWA from scratch, and so far so good.  I've managed to create the app, ask for notification permission, and send a notification if someone accepts or returns to the site (via javascript).  The service worker is running fine.

However, this is where my headache is starting, as i just can't get my head round sending notifications either if the app is open or closed - what i am trying to get to is where i can send some sort of update app on demand, maybe from a web page from my machine that pushes out to everyone who has the app installed.

I've looked at many tutorials, and they all reference web-push but this appears to be Linux based.  My web server is Windows based, so i don't know if there is an windows equivalent of web-push that can be used for push notifications. I haven't been able to google any answers that help.
I can build a Linux server with web-push, but i am assuming this needs to be internet facing which i don't have the ability to do.

I ideally would like to do this all from my own web server, rather than a web based service, and ideally a service which is free :)

Can someone give me a basic overview to get me started on sending notifications please - i think once i have the basics i'll be able to work it out, it's just getting started i need help with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to update. i'm sorted with this - was having a bad day i think.  i didn't realise there was a windows version from here https://nodejs.org/en/download which i could install on my server and run from there.